# Is there a DAG with weighted edges?

Tags: jgrapht

I'd like to create a DAG in order to use the `TopologicalOrderIterator` and would like to save some weights on the edges. However, a DAG does not allow weighted edges and the `TopologicalOrderIterator` is not available for a `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph`. Am I missing something and this combination should somehow be forbidden or did I just not find the right classes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future posts, please include a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
Remember to accept and upvote a response if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to correct two wrong statements: (1) a DAG does allow weighted edges and (2) a `TopologicalOrderIterator` does exist for the `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph`.

Here's an example of using a `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph` with the `TopologicalOrderIterator`:

```
//Create a standard directed weighted graph. This graph type allows cycles, so, to maintain the acyclic property,
// it's the users responsibility not to add any arcs that create cycles.
Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = GraphTypeBuilder.<Integer,DefaultWeightedEdge> directed().weighted(true).buildGraph();
Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4));
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 0,1, 10); //Adds a directed arc from vertex 0 to vertex 1 with weight 10
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 0,2, 11);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 1,2, 12);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,3, 13);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,4, 14);
TopologicalOrderIterator<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> it = new TopologicalOrderIterator<>(graph);
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Note that in this example, to construct the graph, I used the builder paradigm. Instead of

```
Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = GraphTypeBuilder.<Integer,DefaultWeightedEdge> directed().weighted(true).buildGraph();
```

I could have written:

```
Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
```

Alternatively you could use the specialized `DirectedAcyclicGraph` graph format:

```
DirectedAcyclicGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(null, SupplierUtil.createDefaultWeightedEdgeSupplier(),true);
Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4));
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 0,1, 10); //Adds a directed arc from vertex 0 to vertex 1 with weight 10
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 0,2, 11);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 1,2, 12);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,3, 13);
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,4, 14);
Iterator<Integer> it = graph.iterator(); //Creates a Topological order iterator
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Note that the following code would be incorrect:

```
DirectedAcyclicGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(0,1));
Graphs.addEdge(graph, 0, 1, 10); //Adds a directed arc from vertex 0 to vertex 1 with weight 10
```

This creates an *unweighted* graph and then attempts to add a weighted edge. This would result in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jgrapht.graph.BaseIntrusiveEdgesSpecifics.setEdgeWeight(BaseIntrusiveEdgesSpecifics.java:138)
```

In order to create a weighted version of the `DirectedAcyclicGraph`, the correct constructor should be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. I tried it with the last approach `DirectedAcyclicGraph` with `DefaultWeightedEdge` and ran into the `UnsupportedOperationException`. However, both other approaches are working fine for me.

Comment: @chrisb if the answer answered your question, click the 'accept answer' button such that others know what the correct answer is. This way, other people with the same problem immediately find the corresponding solution.